# как прописать обработчик нажатия на дату в Mainactivity.java в android studio

Tags: java, android

Создал простой календарь в *android studio*  [image: календарь]
Мой `MainActivity.java` выглядит так:

```
package ru.nick.p007_dataaplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на любую дату появлялось два цвета, на которые можно изменить ту или иную дату, примерно вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения].
Вопрос: как это сделать программно, как должен выглядеть код?

Понимаю, что нужно задать обработчик нажатия на дату, но как это выглядит нигде не могу найти. Мне отвечают, что выбор цвета сможешь реализовать на *FragmentDialog*. Но как выглядит код с *FragmentDiaLog*? Как выглядит код обработчика нажатия на дату? Как это реализовать(ответ желательно с примером) чтобы было понятно новичку?

после полученных ответов делаю некоторое дополнение (пояснение) для более точного понимания моего вопроса...

дополнение от 27,02,2016

хорошо, вас понял. попытаюсь конкретизировать. Как прописать код чтобы принимал сигнал от пользователя при нажатии им на дату и  после нажатия на любую дату появлялся выбор поменять цвет ячейки даты на  зелёный либо красный. Пользователь выбирает из предлагаемого выбора цвет(красный либо зеленый), нажимает на него и ячейка в которой находится дата меняется на выбранный пользователем цвет. как это будет выглядеть в виде кода?   Либо по-другому это представить, есть календарь, над календарем две простые кнопки: 1 - зеленого цвета;2 - красного цвета. Как прописать код, что бы пользователь мог нажать на любую из двух кнопок (красную либо зеленую) после чего автоматически при нажатии на любые даты цвет меняется на соответствующий. Например, пользователь нажимает на кнопку красного цвета, затем нажимает последовательно на з даты, допустим 3.03.2016, 4.03.2016, 5.03.2016 (даты из календаря), и все ячейки выбранных дат становятся красного цвета. Попытался объяснить как мог, если тоже не понятно, перефразирую

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтоб отследить дату при нажатии, на `calendarView` можно повесить обработчик `setOnDateChangeListener` выглядеть будет так:

```
CalendarView cw = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.cw);
    cw.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Можно поменять цвет при нажатии, но нужно знать что вы хотите. Вот пару идей как это сделать:

1.Сделать свою разметку и шаманить, как вам угодно.

2.Менять стиль при нажатии на дату.(Что-то мне подсказывает что это не то что вам нужно)

Я оставлю подсказку, какие стили - за какие элементы отвечают в виджете. Также вы можете сделать кастомный calendarView, но особо там ничего не добьетесь, так как класс работает со стилями и об этом написано сразу, вот шпаргалка:

```
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_showWeekNumber
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_firstDayOfWeek
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_minDate
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_maxDate
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_shownWeekCount
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_selectedWeekBackgroundColor
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_focusedMonthDateColor
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_unfocusedMonthDateColor
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_weekNumberColor
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_weekSeparatorLineColor
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_selectedDateVerticalBar
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_weekDayTextAppearance
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#CalendarView_dateTextAppearance
```

Вот нашел сразу выдержку из en-StackOverFLow, изменения в `style.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:Theme">
  <item name="android:calendarViewStyle">@style/Widget.CalendarView.Custom</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.CalendarView.Custom" parent="android:Widget.CalendarView">
    <item name="android:focusedMonthDateColor">@color/cs_textcolor</item>
    <item name="android:weekNumberColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:weekDayTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:dateTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
</style>
```

Comment: спасибо, но не помогло. как поменять цвет так и не понятно

Comment: всё, что описано в этом ответе 100% рабочие моменты и их реализация решит вашу проблему. Если вы хотите получить подробный рабочий код, попробуйте конкретизировать ваш вопрос на части, тк на данный момент он звучит: "сделайте мне", но нет сути проблемы, так же как и ваш комментарий. Что именно не помогло? что именно не получилось?

Comment: сделал для вас дополнение от 27.02.2016. надеюсь более точно будет понятен мой вопрос, в чем у меня трудность. заранее благодарен за быстрые ответы

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Слушатель рабочий в ответе, на этот слушатель вешаете dialog какой вам удобней, где идёт выбор цвета, от этого выбора будет зависеть какой стиль вы примените к этой дате.

Comment: спасибо, попробую